# default constructor is it called or not in this example

Tags: java, constructor

I have this class

```
class A {

  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

  A() {
    a = 3;
    b = 4;
  }

}
```

This is constructor here which initialize two instance variables. What happens to the third instance variable? Is it going to be initialized by the default constructor? If yes, what would the order of call be?

Comment: Fields have "default values" and constructors execute code after "field initialization". This will be explained in a [Java Trail / Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Why don't you just call that constructor, and then print the value of c? Or just read your Java text book?

Comment: Please investigate some more by yourself before asking these type of questions

Comment: by which c is initialized ?

Comment: `c` is never assigned/initialized in the shown code. As a field, it has a "default value". Please see the Tutorial links above. Likewise, `a` and `b` are *assigned values* in the constructor, but are not subject to "field initialization". Please see the Tutorial links above.

Comment: Voting to close as a homework dump.

Comment: when we instanciate the class a call to constructor to initialize a and b but is the default constructor called to initialize c with zero ?

Comment: JB Nizet the construcor will initialize only a and b but not c right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decompile your class using `javap`, you'll find:

```
Compiled from "A.java"
class A {
  int a;

  int b;

  int c;

  A();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: iconst_3
       6: putfield      #2                  // Field a:I
       9: aload_0
      10: iconst_4
      11: putfield      #3                  // Field b:I
      14: return
}
```

Even without knowing what this bytecode means, you can see that `a` and `b` are mentioned in the constructor (this is where they are assigned in the constructor), but the only mention of `c` is in the field declaration, `int c`. So nothing happens to `c` in the constructor.

Because it is not explicitly initialized, it will have the default initial value, as described in [JLS Sec 4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
> - ...
> - For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
> - ...

So `c` will have the value zero, but not as a result of the invocation of the constructor (which is distinct from the creation of the instance, as far as the JVM is concerned).

Comment: are a and b initialized by zero and initalized another time by constructor ?

Comment: @A.Spencer yes, that is what the excerpt from the language spec says. And, indeed, you would find this, if you printed the value of the field before you assign it.

Comment: one more question if there was no constructors in the class so a call to the default constructor will be performed, what is the need of reinitializing variables one more time but they were already initialized to the same default value ?